# Load option tags with Ajax

Tags: json, jquery

In my aspx page I have a  element prefilled with 50 options displaying the first 50 clients). 
In order to implement paging for this control (in total there would be 5000 clients) I have then developed a stored procedure (SQL Server). Passing the current index, the sp returns the next/previous 50 records.

```
 <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="contactsList" SelectionMode="Multiple" />    

 <input type="button" id="PrevButton" value="Prev"/>
 <input type="button" id="NextButton" value="Next"/>
```

Now using Ajax/JSON to invoke a web method I would like to call such sp and replace the current options with the new 50s returned from the DB.

If I return the resultset with the web method, how could I then be able to use it within a jQuery script to replace the options and avoiding a postBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var request = $.ajax({

    url: your_request_url,
    data: anyDataYouWishToPass,
    success: function( data ) {

        $('#contactsList').html(data);

    }

});
```

Comment: But my web method would return a List with clientID and clientName, to be used as value and text for the option respectively. If I use directly html() methid i do not think the options would be properly initiated. However I might create the html on server side and return that, like: <option value="xyz"> Charles </option>.

Comment: You should also look into jQuery $.tmpl method which allows you to use name/value pairs and echo the values into your markup. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/